# Why do we always consider intervals when using pre-images instead of specific points on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose we have a measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mu$), and there is a function $F$ which maps $\omega \in \Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

And the pre-image of this function $F$, a random variable, maps an interval on $\mathbb{R}$ to $\omega \in \mathcal{F}$.

We then say that $F^{-1}([a,b]) = \{\omega \in \Omega: F(\omega) \in [a,b]\} \in \mathcal{F}$ for $a < b$.

My question is, why do we consider the interval $[a,b]$, instead of just a a single point, $a$?

Comment: Well in general we are interested in measurable maps $F:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. But measurable maps are such that the preimage of measurable sets is measurable. Sets of the form $[a,b]$ generate the sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. That's a general reason to care about these intervals and wonder about their preimages. Why are you interested, in particular, at looking at $F^{-1}(a)$ intead?

Comment: In addition to the comment above, singletons are contained in the Borel sigma algebra. So it is also true that $F^{-1}(\{a\}) \in \mathscr{F}$.